# Conda not recognized by terminal, even though it is in PATH

Tags: python, windows, conda, mini-forge

I had multiple problems with my installation of Python on my Windows machine, which made me want to uninstall everything (Python, Anaconda, etc.) and just set it up again from scratch. That also made it possible to use Miniforge3 instead of the commercial Anaconda.

I installed the latest version of Miniforge3 for Windows 10 (just for my user) and checked the prompt to add Miniforge3 to `PATH`. This did work, as I found a directory in the user environment `PATH`.

This makes it very weird to me, that neither the Windows terminal nor Miniforge Prompt recognizes `conda` or `python`. Every answer on here or elsewhere points to add it to the `PATH`, but from what I understood, it should be enough to have the necessary directories in the uses environment variables.

The main problem:

- Neither the terminal, nor Miniforge Prompt recognizes `conda` or `python`, so no environments can be activated and no scripts can be run

What I tried:

1. Installation with automatic addition to `PATH`
2. Installation with manual addition to `PATH` after the installation was finished

What the user `PATH` looks like:

- C:\Users\firstname lastname\miniforge3
- C:\Users\firstname lastname\miniforge3\Library\mingw-w64\bin
- C:\Users\firstname lastname\miniforge3\Library\usr\bin
- C:\Users\firstname lastname\miniforge3\Library\bin
- C:\Users\firstname lastname\miniforge3\Scripts
- ...

the `_conda.exe` file is located in the first directory of the `PATH`

Comment: Hi, try to add some screenshots or cmd logs to your question to make it clear what is going on, also tell in the question what kind of operating system are you using like windows 10 or 11 or? and its version.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please [edit] to reveal your actual `PATH` and the location of the `conda` binary.